# VBA return next value from for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I need to populate a cell with each value from a `For` loop.  I have a worksheet with Employee Names and Employee IDs.  I am attempting to populate cells on another worksheet and print to default printer (or PDF preferred), then do the same for the next employee in the list.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  What I currently have only returns the first employee name and no ID.

```
Sub btn_CompleteForm()

Dim Rng As Range, cell As Range, EmpName As Range
Set NameRng = Range("Employees!A2:Employees!A10")
Set IDRng = Range("Employees!B2:Employees!B10")
Set EmpName = Range("ActionNotice!D7")
Set EmpID = Range("ActionNotice!D8")

For Each cell In NameRng
    EmpName = NameRng.Value
    EmpID = IDRng.Value
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    MsgBox "Next"
Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should only require one simple fix.  Change `EmpName = NameRng.Value` to `EmpName = cell.Value` you are looping through `cell` up to `NameRng`, not looping through `NameRng`.

```
Sub btn_CompleteForm()
    Dim Rng As Range, cell As Range, EmpName As Range
    With Worksheets("ActionNotice")
        For Each cell In Range("Employees!A2:Employees!A10")
            .Range("D7") = cell.value                 'Name
            .Range("D8") = cell.Offset(0, 1).value    'ID
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
                                                 IgnorePrintAreas:=False
            MsgBox "Next"
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: in your case `IDRng.Value` would always point to the ID in first row?

Comment: I really appreciate the help! That works great for returning the employee name, but it is still not returning the employee ID.

Comment: Oh, that's my mistake.  I'll edit it to add the `offset` to move over one column

Comment: I accidentally edit your question.  Sorry about that.  I don't think that I can roll it back.

Comment: That's not a problem at all!  It's written better now.

Comment: One last thing...if I want the range to be dynamic, so employees can be added, what would I replace "Range("Employees!A2:Employees!A10")" with?

Comment: `Range("c1", Range("c1").End(xlDown))` this does the same thing as clicking `ctrl + down arrow` in VBA.  You just have to make sure that there aren't any skips in the column, or it will stop at the first skip.

Answer (score 2):

```
   For Each cell In NameRng
        EmpName = NameRng.Value
        EmpID = IDRng.Value
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False
        MsgBox "Next"
    Next cell
```

Should be

```
   For nRow = 1 to NameRng.Count
        EmpName.Value = NameRng.Cells(nRow,1).Value
        EmpID.Value = IDRng.Cells(nRow,1).Value
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False
        MsgBox "Next"
    Next nRow
```

Comment: The issue in your code block was `cell` iterates to have different values in `NameRng`.But for all the values `NameRng.Value` will always point to the first value, thus printing same Name for all rows.

Comment: I really appreciate the help! That works great for returning the employee name, but it is still not returning the employee ID.

Comment: Note you should do `EmpID = IDRng.Cells(i,1)` and not `EmpID = IDRng.Value`

Comment: Thanks.  I am using the code copied from your revision and it still isn't returning the ID.  Should the NameRng be changed to A2:B10 instead of treating NameRng and IDRng as separate ranges?

Comment: @JustinHill can you upload the workbook for me to take a look?

Comment: One check I would do is replace `MsgBox "Next"` with `MsgBox EmpName&EmpID`. This would help in checking if the iterations are working fine.

Comment: Also I made a small edit to make the code a little more safer, by using `.Value` on Range object.